# How to test something "NOT" receiving

Tags: test-design, testcase

I came across this question from a colleague.

He asked me how to specify one or more test cases from a specification, that does NOT expect a signal. In other words:

```
if anyVariable == true
  ComponentX must not send a signal to ComponentY
```

If anyVariable is true, some stuff is executed and afterwards anyVariable is set back to false.

I had 2 ideas:

1. Just test whether ComponentY does not receive a signal iff anyVariable is true (weak)
2. Do as in (1) but wait some time

In addition to (2) one could wait as long as anyVariable == false again. 
But what if it never becomes false again?

Are there some other approaches to test a "scenario" like described above?

Thanks for any ideas or discussions.

Comment: `If anyVariable is true, some stuff is executed` - this execution should be your expected result I think.

Comment: @HelpingHands This execution will be the expected result for `some stuff is executed`, not for `must not send a signal`.

Comment: @HelpingHands That would just check whether "some stuff" is executed iff anyVariable == true, wouldn't it? Thus, that do not imply an absence of a signal at ComponentY.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether you have access of your project internal database or logs of any jobs that need to process your data, but this would be your best try IMHO.
For example, let's take your example:

```
    if anyVariable == true
       ComponentX MUST NOT send a signal to ComponentY
```

Normally, since `ComponentX` will not send a signal to `ComponentY` leaves you kind of naked, with not much that you could do. In this case, you should go the opposite way. Based on your example that will be:

```
if anyVariable == false
       ComponentX MUST send a signal to ComponentY
```

Basically, this means that `ComponentX` will be processed by a job (e.g. ESP, API, WebService, etc) or just trigger some SP from your DB, just to mention a few. Well, now this means that a trace of that processing will remain somewhere, like some logs for your job, data updated or inserted in your database, etc.

Now, going back, to follow your example, to verify the "not happening" functionality, you will check that there are no traces in the locations mentioned above. This will assure that what doesn't need to happen will not.

Of course, this all depends on how the application under test is built, because usually developers will want to have some traces for "not happening" features too, mostly for debugging purposes.

Comment: Consequently, I could read the logs to check whether the log information are "paused" during anyVariable==true?

Comment: Short answer is yes. 
Long answer would be to sit down with the developers and see exactly how they handled this. Maybe the log information are "paused" as you said, or maybe some different information is logged when no actions are taken per your condition. 
Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you run your tests from the perspective of ComponentX?

Figure out all possible equivalence classes for inputs and then validate the expected outputs (or lack of output) of ComponentX.